# Client is not recieving message sent by server

Tags: java, javafx

Basically i m using jfx for communication between clients and server So for checking I m sending message from server to client to stop his work .So in order to simplify my problem I made this sample program. Upon pressing button it server sends `Stop` message to all clients. Here is the my code

`myController1` class

```
 public class myController1 extends Stage implements Initializable {
        @FXML TextArea snames;
        tcpserver server;
        public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
            server=new tcpserver(8088);
            Task<Void> t=new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    server.start();
                    return null;
                }
            };
            new Thread(t).start();
        }
        public void Pressed(ActionEvent E) throws IOException{
            server.sendToAll("Stop");
        }
    }
```

`tcpclient` class

```
public class tcpclient {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Running");
        String hostName="127.0.0.1";
        int port=8088;
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = 
                      new Socket(hostName, port);
            while(true)
            {

                BufferedReader inFromServer=new 
                         BufferedReader(new 
                                 InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    String FromServer=inFromServer.readLine(); 
                System.out.println("From Server "+FromServer); 
                if(FromServer.equals("Stop"))
                {
                    break;
                }   
            }   
            clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

`sendToAll` Function that sends message to all connected clients

```
public void sendToAll(String message) throws IOException{
        for(Socket client : clientsSockets)
        {
            System.out.println(":"+message);
            DataOutputStream outToServer =  null;
            outToServer = new 
                    DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()); 
            outToServer.writeBytes(message);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your class names should be capitalized and variables should beLikeSuch. Anyway, where's the server code?

Comment: In your `sendToAll()` method, there is no need to set the `DataOutputStream` to null, then initialize it.